# ubuntu indicator applet that has a dynamic menu item

Tags: python, indicator, gtk

I'm working on a simple indicator in Ubuntu with python and I want the menuitem to display the return of a function and refresh every "n" second.

Here is what I have:

```
def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    item_internetstatus = gtk.MenuItem("Internet : " + internetstatus())
    menu.append(item_internetstatus)
```

The function is internetstatus() and my objective is to run internetstatus() every n seconds so that the menuitem label is also updated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your init (or wherever you initialise stuff) set up a timer:

```
refreshIntervalInMinutes = 5
GLib.timeout_add_seconds( refreshIntervalInMinutes, build_menu )
```

Then ensure the last line of build_menu() returns True so the timer is continually called.

Comment: I have since added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you to call your function at a given rate and display the result in the panel which may suit rather than rebuilding the menu each time.